# Troubleshooting Avatar Upload Issue in PHP

Tags: php

The function seems correct, but uploads are unsuccessful. I've checked file types, sizes and paths, but I'm unable to identify the issue . The code is not producing any error messages, making debugging challenging. Any insights or suggestions for improvements would be highly appreciated. Also, if you could share potential security considerations for avatar uploads, that would be great. Thank you!

```
class myUser {    
public function uploadAvatar(){
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);

        if (
            ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/gif") || 
            ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/jpeg") ||
            ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/jpg") ||
            ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/pjpeg") ||
            ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/x-png") ||
            ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/png") &&
            ($_FILES['avatar']['size'] < 500000000) &&
            in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
        ) {
            if ($_FILES['avatar']['error'] > 0) {
                redirect('register.php', $_FILES['avatar']['error'], 'error');
            } else {
                $targetPath = "images/avatars/";  // Adjust the path as needed
                $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
    
                if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
                    redirect('register.php', 'File already exists', 'error');
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $targetFile);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            redirect('register.php', 'Invalid File Type!', 'error');
        }
    }
}

// Separate file below

$user = new MyUser;

if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $data = array();
    $data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $data['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $data['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $data['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
    $data['password2'] = md5($_POST['password2']);
    $data['about'] = $_POST['about'];
    $data['last_activity'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $user->uploadAvatar();

    if($user->uploadAvatar()) {
        $data['avatar'] = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
    } else {
        $data['avatar'] = 'noimage.png';
    }

}


<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="register.php">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Upload Avatar</label>
    <input type="file" name="avatar">
    <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
    <input name="register_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Comment: From PHP's [md5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) manual: "_Warning It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See the [Password Hashing FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) for details and best practices._"

Comment: `isset($_POST['register'])` will never trigger, no element with that name